# Taxonomyinternalservice.json

Tags: metadata

I am having a list which fetches the metadata termsets. But it is taking very long time to get the results. I have checked this in Fiddler and it is the following line of code is taking more time. Please let me know how do I fix this.

_vti_bin/taxonomyinternalservice.json/GetMatches